# How to manage Akka Actor's paths in distributed system?

Tags: akka

Suppose I have a the following two Actors

1. Store
2. Product

Every Store can have multiple Products and I want to dynamically split the Store into StoreA and StoreB on high traffic on multiple machines. The splitting of Store will also split the Products evenly between StoreA and StoreB.

**My question is:** what are the best practices of knowing where to send all the future `BuyProduct` requests to (StoreA or StoreB) after the split ? The reason I'm asking this is because if a request to buy ProductA is received I want to send it to the right store which already has that Product's state in memory.

**Solution:** The only solution I can think of is to store the path of each Product `Map[productId:Long, storePath:String]` in a ProductsPathActor every time a new Product is created and for every `BuyProduct` request I will query the ProductPathActor which will return the correct Store's path and then send the `BuyProduct` request to that Store ?

Is there another way of managing this in Akka or is my solution correct ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to do this is with [Akka Cluster Sharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-sharding.html). From the docs:

> Cluster sharding is useful when you need to distribute actors across
>   several nodes in the cluster and want to be able to interact with them
>   using their logical identifier, but without having to care about their
>   physical location in the cluster, which might also change over time.

There is an Activator Template that demonstrates it [here](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-cluster-sharding-scala).

To your problem, the concept of `StoreA` and `StoreB` are each a `ShardRegion` and map 1:1 with to your cluster nodes. The `ShardCoordinator` manages distribution between these nodes and acts as the conduit between regions.

For it's part, your Request Handler talks to a `ShardRegion`, which routes the message if necessary in conjunction with the coordinator. Presumably, there is a JVM-local `ShardRegion` for each Request Handler to talk to, but there's no reason that it could not be a remote actor.

When there is a change in the number of nodes, `ShardCoordinator` needs to move shards (i.e. the collections of entities that were managed by that `ShardRegion`) that are going to shut down in a process called "rebalancing". During that period, the  entities within those shards are unavailable, but the messages to those entities will be buffered until they are available again. To this end, "being available" means that the new `ShardRegion` responds to a directed message for that entity.

It's up to you to bring that entity back to life on the new node. [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/persistence.html) makes this very easy, but requires you to use the [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) pattern in the process. This isn't a bad thing, as it can lead to web-scale performance much more easily. This is especially true when the database in use is something like [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org). You will see that nodes are "passivated", which is essentially just caching off to disk so they can be restored on request, and Akka Persistence works with that passivation to transparently restore the nodes under the control of the new `ShardRegion` – essentially a "move".

Comment: Thank you :). I'm looking at the template and the documentation but I think it will take me some time to figure this out. But will Cluster sharding automatically split Store to StoreA and StoreB and also distribute the Store's children[Product] evenly between StoreA & StoreB ?

Comment: Great! I hope that the updates above are sufficient to help you consider the question "answered". There are also some aspects of this that I am not 100% familiar with (or have forgotten since I have been looking at other things since I first studied it), but hopefully this synopsis is enough to get you going.